# How do I get LibreOffice Writer to start page numbers at 1 and not 0?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I have a book where the first page of actual content, after title pages and copyright notices and so on, is on the fifth page of the file. I want that page to be marked as page number 1.

I set a footer, put a page number field in it, and set the offset to -5. This successfully makes it so the page numbers start their count from the fifth page of the file. So that part is working.

However, the number that is displaying on the first page of content is "0", not "1".

How do I get the numbering to start at 1 and not 0?

Comment: Does this answer help?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040080/libreoffice-page-number-bug/11040854#11040854

Comment: @tohuwawohu, thank you for that link. The advice there almost solves the problem. By using the `Format - Paragraph - Text flow` method, the first page of the main body does now start at 1 and not 0. But, the preceding pages now have numbers, so that the first pages of my book are numbered `1,2,3,4,1,2...`. I want those first four pages before the content begins to not have any numbers at all. How do I clear the numbers out of the first four pages, while keeping the fifth page as page #1?

Comment: I didn't test it, but i assume you can disable page numbers for the first part of your document by modifying the page style of that part. In the Page Style, on the `Page` tab, there are "`Layout setting`" parameters. In the "`Format`" combobox, select "`None`". That should do the trick.

Comment: Please note: If you want different page numbering for different page ranges in the same document, i assume you'll have to create custom page styles. Modifying the page style as described above will apply to the whole document, if there's only one (default) page style for the complete document.

Comment: @tohuwawohu, Thank you for your following up. I was able to remove the page numbers on the first few pages by creating a new page style for them and then selecting `none` in the `format` box, as you described. This issue is now solved for me. It seems there is additional information in your comments that would justify an answer to this question. If you put an answer, I'll mark it correct.